# in bash script unexpected "syntax error: unexpected end of file" on if statement

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, syntax-error, unexpectendoffile

W/hen i run the following code snippet

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "foo" = "foo" ];
then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
echo "end"
```

i get

```
sfm_write_buffer_test.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

this doesn't make any sense. echo statements works fine, but when the if statement is encountered it gives the above mentioned error.

Comment: Try removing the trailing semicolon on the if statement

Comment: I just copy-and-pasted the above into a script on my system and ran it.  The output was two lines: `true` and `end`.  Same result with bash versions 2.01.1, 3.2.25, and 4.2.8.

Comment: This is one of our most regular FAQs. Surprised it took this long for a close-as-duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're on Cygwin, right?

As I said in a comment, when I copy-and-paste your script and run it on my system, it works; the output is

```
true
end
```

But when I change the line endings from the Unix style `'\n'` to the Windows style `'\r\n'`, I get the same error you got.

With the Windows-style line endings, bash doesn't see the `then` keyword; it sees a command named `then\r`.  It never tries to execute it because it's scanning for the matching `then` or `fi` for the `if` keyword (which it recognized because it's not at the end of the line).

Make sure your shell scripts use Unix-style line endings.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the CRLF at the end of the script.  Shell scripts throw this error when they see Windows-style line endings.  You need to replace line endings in your shell script with Unix-style LF.  Each IDE has it's own way of doing this.

> **Sublime Text 2** ==> View -> Line Endings -> Unix
>
> **Notepad++** ==> Edit -> EOL Conversion -> UNIX/OSX Format

Once you make that change and save the file, the shell script should execute without error.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't your specific problem, but this can also happen if you have pasted an indented heredoc inside your if statement and it has been converted from tabs to spaces. The end delimiter of the heredoc is never found because of the whitespace, and unexpected end of file is the result.