# OpenCV C++ with Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have checked a lot of threads already but none of them seems to solve my problem. I'm working on a project regarding my study and want to use the OpenCV library with my Android app. Here is a list of the programs and tools I use:

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (3.7.0)
- Android SDK r16
- OpenCV 2.3.1
- Android NDK r7b

I am following a tutorial, and everything works fine until the part where I need the NDK for using C++ OpenCV code. I can code and run Android apps and the "Tutorial 1" samples from the OpenCV 2.3.1 are working fine. However the "Tutorial 2" samples won't work. I tried following the steps in the C++ part of the tutorial.

When I try to run the NDK-build (tried both the command line and Eclipse part) I keep getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/opencv/cvjni.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone has a solution for my problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[in bash script unexpected "syntax error: unexpected end of file" on if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237118/in-bash-script-unexpected-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-on-if-statement)

> Make sure your shell scripts use Unix-style line endings

Comment: Thanks for the help. However i have no idea how to fix the problem while using Command Prompt. Instead I used Cygwin with the following commands:  First navigate to your project folder:  cd /cygdrive/c/androidDevelopment/android-opencv/TestOpenCV/  While in this folder use the path to your ndk-build file:  /cygdrive/c/androidDevelopment/android-ndk-r7b/ndk-build  
It starts compiling and after that I can run the app on my tablet